# iframe file upload or jquery are escaping my string

Tags: jquery, iframe, escaping

I am writing a javascript&jquery-backend and using the standard ajax meme of iframe file upload.

We need to use javascript `eval()` (yes, i know) on a string returned by the server. 
The string could be something like this (but isn't always so we do need eval):

```
$("#uploaderCinfo").html("<h1>file(s) received</h1>");
```

The server, firebug, fiddler tell me that that is exactly what it sends (plus the http-header):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 54

$("#uploaderCinfo").html("<h1>file(s) received</h1>");
```

However what i get from the iframe is this:

```
<pre>$("#uploaderCinfo").html("&lt;h1&gt;file(s) received&lt;/h1&gt;");</pre>
```

I assume there's a good reason why the `<pre>'s` are added, and i can remove them using `slice()`. But where does the escaping within the html-string come from?

This way *`<h1>file(s) received</h1>`* is added verbatim into the page because the <'s were escaped somehow. **Can i prevent the escaping or do i have to use a javascript-means to revert it?**

Thanks for any help.

*For reference: Minimal usable source following*:
*(Note: the single-quotes escape into Smalltalk in which the sessions are generated)*

```
self plain: '<div id="uploadform',uUpload,'">
    <form id="theuploadform',uUpload,'" method="post" action="">
        <input id="userfile',uUpload,'" name="userfile',uUpload,'" 
            size="10" type="file" multiple />
        <input id="formsubmit',uUpload,'" type="submit" value="upload" 
            onClick="', INSIDE THE ONCLICK (see below) ,'" />
    </form>
<span id="anim',uUpload,'">
</span>
<div id="iframe',uUpload,'" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;">

INSIDE THE ONCLICK:

$("#anim',uUpload,'").html("<img src=''/files/public/loading.gif'' />");
var iframe = $(''<iframe name="postiframe',uUpload,'" 
        id="postiframe',uUpload,'" style="display: none" />'');
    $("body").append(iframe);
    var form = $("#theuploadform',uUpload,'");
    form.attr("action", "/uploadAjax?session=',
        (session at: #zId),'&upload=',uUpload,'");
    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("target", "postiframe',uUpload,'");
    form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.attr("file", $("#userfile',uUpload,'").val());
    form.submit();
    $("#postiframe',uUpload,'").load(function () {
        iframeContents = 
            $("#postiframe',uUpload,'")[0].contentWindow.document
                                                    .body.innerHTML;
        $("#anim',uUpload,'").html(""); /*removes animation*/
    console.log("A");
    console.log(iframeContents);
    console.log("B");
    iframeContents = iframeContents.slice(5, iframeContents.length-6);
    console.log(iframeContents);
    console.log("C");
    eval(iframeContents);
    console.log("D");
    });
    return false;
```

Comment: This is very likely escaped from the server side itself. What server side tech are you using?

Comment: @techfoobar I am writing the server side myself, using only Sockets (in Squeak-Smalltalk). I dont think that the server did this escaping; added the full HTTP-response in the answer. Firebug tells me this also.

Comment: why don't you put it between scrip tag

Comment: @rajeshkakawat the "file(s) received" is just an example. in general the server generates many different JS-responses on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is indeed not the server escaping it but your browser. It adds the `<pre>`'s because it's content is text/plain ( like @Pinal already suggested ).

Am I right about you using FF? ( **Edit:** I just found the bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674186 )

Try using `.textContent` instead of innerHTML when retrieving contents from the iframe.

Also look at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07 which suggests using `var text = x.innerText || x.textContent` For browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's the server-side escape. What is your back-end?

Comment: I am writing the backend myself using only plain sockets (in Squeak-Smalltalk) and both Firebug and Fiddler tell me that the server is NOT the one escaping it.

Comment: I think content-type is wrong `Content-Type: text/plain`. Try **text/html**

Comment: If I do that then `iframeContents` becomes the incomplete `ploaderCinfo").html("<h1>file(s) received</` for some reason. The following JS-eval of that obviously fails. I also tried `application/x-javascript` which does the same as my original.

Comment: Content-Type: text/javascript ?

Comment: `text/javascript` also does the same as my original